# Lua DynAsm: Any reference or links to guide me through?

Tags: assembly, lua, jit

I want to experiment with Lua's [DynASM](http://luajit.org/dynasm.html) (as a fast general purpose JIT engine)

I couldn't find any docs or references to help me with it. Does anybody even use it (outside of LuaJIT of course) ?

Comment: Try asking that question on Lua mailing list. You may (or may not) yield some additional responses.

Comment: The documentation on the site is a bit shallow. I wrote Mike a mail about it a few days ago and fortunately he answered. He gave me this example, which doesn't seem to be linked anywhere on the dynASM page: 
http://luajit.org/download/DynASM-example.tar.gz

Comment: http://blog.reverberate.org/2012/12/hello-jit-world-joy-of-simple-jits.html has a simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the (superficial-ish) research I did a while back, the only documentation is luajits source, which is a bit annoying, and one of the reasons i gave up on it (as the source annoys me profusely, as great as it is)... Imo, unless you somehow get mike pall to sacrifice some time, your on your own, don't let that discourage you though, cause there is nothing to stop you making the unofficial docs(or a wiki) with mikes blessing, and i'm sure he'll answer any questions, just like he does on the lua mailing list.

Comment: Right. Except that in order to write unofficial docs I need some docs to get me started :)

Comment: @bugspy: unfortunatly those 'docs' seem to be the minute example on the dynasm page. Looking again, I stumbled onto this interesting project: https://github.com/thoughtpolice/dynasm-example